# How can I make touch events (on the dom) bubble in javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, touch

It looks to me like touch events just don't bubble, even tho [everyone seems to say or imply that they do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent). I've tested on Chrome 29.0.1547.62 (using the "emulate touch events" override) and android webview (using cordova), neither have event bubbling happening for the touchstart event. Here's an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        #a {
            background-color: red;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #b {
            background-color: blue;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#a').on('touchstart', function(){
                console.log("a start")
            })

            $('#b').on('touchstart', function(){
                console.log("b start")
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Even tho b is on top of a, only b's touchstart event gets triggered when b is touched. Whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not understanding event bubbling.

It doesn't mean that the even touches all surrounding elements. It means that the event goes from the most deeply nested element, all the way up through its ancestors to the `document`, and invokes handlers it finds on the way.

In your HTML,  you have siblings.

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

To make use of bubbling, they would need to be nested.

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: By the way, bonus points if you can tell me how to do what I'm trying to do. Would I have to do element collision calculations manually? I would hope there's a better way

Comment: @BT: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but one possibility may be to put your `"a"` and `"b"` elements inside a container, and put the event handler on the container.

Comment: ...oh, you want to find all elements at the point that was touched, irrespective of their location? I think there's some method to do that, but I'm not sure how. Pretty sure it'll involve a handler on the `document`, then some sort of analysis.